# Google Visualization Datatable to CSV download

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-visualization

Adding to Stack Overflow after leeching for long enough.

What I have:

- Google Visualization product
- Data read from database or table and loaded into datatable.
- Datatable is used to create Google Visualization graphics.
- Button or link to "Download to CSV" which I need to be loaded as per
  the current configuration of the data.  I.e. after all processing and
  changes, including controls.

Now I want to press the downloadCSV javascript function with a datatable (global unfortunately) with the filename.
I have taken the download code from one of the answers from the thread... [is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

I hope people find this helpful.

Raven

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Initial Part extracted from [Visualization: Area Chart][2]

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      var data;

      function drawChart() {
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }


// Additional Code

    function downloadCSV(filename) {
        jsonDataTable = data.toJSON();
        var jsonObj = eval('(' + jsonDataTable + ')'); 
        output = JSONObjtoCSV(jsonObj,',');
    }

    function JSONObjtoCSV(jsonObj, filename){
    filename = filename || 'download.csv';
        var body = '';      var j = 0;
        var columnObj = []; var columnLabel = []; var columnType = [];
        var columnRole = [];    var outputLabel = []; var outputList = [];
        for(var i=0; i<jsonObj.cols.length; i++){
            columnObj = jsonObj.cols[i];
            columnLabel[i] = columnObj.label;
            columnType[i] = columnObj.type;
            columnRole[i] = columnObj.role;
            if (columnRole[i] == null) {
                outputLabel[j] = '"' + columnObj.label + '"';
                outputList[j] = i;
                j++;
            }           
        }
        body += outputLabel.join(",") + String.fromCharCode(13);

        for(var thisRow=0; thisRow<jsonObj.rows.length; thisRow++){
            outputData = [];
            for(var k=0; k<outputList.length; k++){
                var thisColumn = outputList[k];
                var thisType = columnType[thisColumn];
                thisValue = jsonObj.rows[thisRow].c[thisColumn].v;
                switch(thisType) {
                    case 'string':
                        outputData[k] = '"' + thisValue + '"'; break;
                    case 'datetime':
                        thisDateTime = eval("new " + thisValue);
                        outputData[k] = '"' + thisDateTime.getDate() + '-' + (thisDateTime.getMonth()+1) + '-' + thisDateTime.getFullYear() + ' ' + thisDateTime.getHours() + ':' + thisDateTime.getMinutes() + ':' + thisDateTime.getSeconds() + '"';  
                        delete window.thisDateTime;
                        break;
                    default:
                        outputData[k] = thisValue;
                }
            }
            body += outputData.join(",");
            body += String.fromCharCode(13);
        }       
        uriContent = "data:text/csv;filename=download.csv," + encodeURIComponent(body);
        newWindow=downloadWithName(uriContent, 'download.csv');
        return(body);
    }

    function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
     // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri
    function eventFire(el, etype){
        if (el.fireEvent) {
            (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
            evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
            el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    }
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    eventFire(link, "click");
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        <button id="CSVDownload" onclick="downloadCSV('download.csv')" title="Download to CSV">Download to CSV</Button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For getting data from a Google Chart, I am not sure of the specifics, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/8FavC/) by @asgallant works. There may be a way to do this with filtered data, but I'm not clever enough to figure it out. Hopefully he will share his insight.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to add a slightly simpler way to do export a google table to CSV. You can use Google Visualization api. Suppose you have the google table called `dataTable` in your scope. Then use the following code to download it as .csv.

**Code:**

```
$('#Export').click(function () {
        var csvFormattedDataTable = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(dataTable);
        var encodedUri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvFormattedDataTable);
        this.href = encodedUri;
        this.download = 'table-data.csv';
        this.target = '_blank';
    });
```

**Explanation:**

Here #Export is an anchor element set up as `<a id="Export" href="#">Download as csv</a>` in your page. Google visualization api's

```
google.visualization.dataTableToCsv()
```

does all the hard work of reformatting the table object as csv. More information on this at [Google Visualization Doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#datatabletocsv).

Here I'm using jQuery selector `$`. If you want to do this without jQuery, replace `$('#Export').click(function () { // Function definition here.});` with `document.getElementById("Export").onclick = function() { // function definition here};`

Once the csv formatted data is returned by the method above, we leverage `download` attribute to download the data as a csv file with the file name `table-data` (you can name this whatever you like.

Important: `download` attribute is not supported by Internet Explorer at the time of this answer. This has been tested with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. For more information [download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) .

Comment: Little update : check this for compatibility : http://caniuse.com/#feat=download (resume : still IE ko)